# JTabel Individual Cell Text Alignment

Tags: java, swing, jtable, alignment, tablecellrenderer

Basically I have a `JTable`, and this `JTabel` will have a product in one cell, and then in the cell directly below it the cost.

The product name should be aligned to the left.
The product cost should be aligned to the right.

I don't actually care what the alignment of other cells in each row is.

So I need to set the alignment of either individual cells, or individual rows.  I've found ways to set the alignment of the table, and ways to set the alignment of the columns, but never the rows/individual cells.

**sscce**:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Main();
    }
    public Main(){
        super("Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
             Object rows[] = new Object[50];
             public int getColumnCount(){return 1;}
             public int getRowCount(){return rows.length;}
             public Object getValueAt(int row, int col){ 
                 return rows[row];
             }
             public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
                 return false; 
             }
             public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                 rows[row] = value;
                 fireTableCellUpdated(row,0);
             }
         };

        JTable receipt = new JTable(dataModel);
        receipt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        receipt.setShowGrid(false);
        add(receipt,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2){
            receipt.setValueAt("ProductNameHere",i,0);
            receipt.setValueAt("Cost",i+1,0);
        }
        validate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: Install a custom `TableCellRenderer`, and set the alignment on the `JLabel` inside it as appropriate for your cell.

Comment: Based on the object value past to the cell renderer, change the alignment of the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 4):

The [default renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for `Number` is a right aligned label. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513), no special renderer is required to right align `INT_COL`, which is labeled `Index` and has type `Integer.class`.

[image]

If this is not helpful, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach and your `cost` data type.

Addendum: Alternatively, override `prepareRender()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6852973/230513).

[image]

```
JTable receipt = new JTable(dataModel) {
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
        JLabel c = (JLabel) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        if (row % 2 == 0) {
            c.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        } else {
            c.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }

    public Main() {
        super("Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        TableModel dataModel = new AbstractTableModel() {
            Object rows[] = new Object[10];

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return rows.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
                return rows[row];
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
                rows[row] = value;
                fireTableCellUpdated(row, 0);
            }
        };

        JTable receipt = new JTable(dataModel) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
                JLabel c = (JLabel) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
                if (row % 2 == 0) {
                    c.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
                } else {
                    c.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);

                }
                return c;
            }
        };
        receipt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        receipt.setShowGrid(false);
        add(receipt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
            receipt.setValueAt("ProductNameHere", i, 0);
            receipt.setValueAt(Integer.valueOf(i + 1), i + 1, 0);
        }
        pack();
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a sscce...  As I said, I already know how to implement separate alignments for columns, I need separate alignment for cells or rows.

Comment: +1, for implementing getColumnClass() so the default renderers can be used correctly.

Comment: *The product name should be aligned to the left. The product cost should be aligned to the right*. Product name is a column and product cost is a second column. Based on your requirement you need column alignment, not cell alignment. Your SSCCE only shows 2 columns so I don't understand your comment about cell alignment.

Comment: @csga5000: Alternatively, override `prepareRender()`; I defer to camickr's [article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6852973/230513) on the topic.

Comment: My SSCCE shows 1 column.  I never said that name was a column, as it is not, and neither is cost.  I said "a product in one cell, and then in the cell directly below it the cost", all in 1 column.

Comment: Sorry, when I see a table with two setValueAt(..) methods in a loop I thought you were populating a row with two columns since you are using a JTable. I generally use a JList for single column components. Either overriding prepareRenderer() or creating a custom renderer can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks tons.  I actually could use a JList or something, but I decided against it because, I figured I might want to add a second column later, and because I'm less familiar with tables, and I wanted to figure them out.  Once you understood what I was doing, you were extremely helpful, thanks tons.