# How to change string length (calculating its width in pixel) when changing window size and strange behaviour of JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have `JLabel` which I would like to change its size while I resize the window. When `JLabel` contains String which is too big, the String should be shortened, with **right part** visible and adds **dots on the left hand side** of the String.

My `JLabel` is inside `innerPanel` which is a header in `middlePanel` which is added to `outerPanel`. So when I resize window I use listener on `outerPanel` in that way:

```
outerPanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
       int width = ((JPanel) evt.getSource()).getWidth();
       windowSize = width;
       refresh();
    }

    // [...] other not used override methods
});
```

`refresh()` repaints view and creates new `middlePanel` where is called class which creates `innerPanel` where is located my `JLabel`:

```
Public class InnerPanel extends JPanel {
    private int maxSize;
    String string = "<VERY_LONG_STRING>";
    private static final int DEFAULT_INDEND_PIXEL = 70;

    public InnerPanel(int windowSize) {
        maxSize = windowSize - DEFAULT_INDENT_PIXEL;
        createPanel();
    }

    private createPanel() {
        // [...] gridbag and GridBagConstraints implementation

        String shortString = countString();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(shortString);
        add(label,gc);
    }

    private String countString() {
        int index = 0;
        boolean toBig = true;  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);

        while(toBig) {
            Rectangle2d rect = // [...] code which creates rectangle around text from sb.toString()
            // I have no access to repo at home but if it's important I can paste it tomorrow

            if(rect.getWidth() > maxSize)
                sb.deleteCharAt(0);
            else
                toBig = false;
        }

        return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

That's works fine in general, bacause it do resize `JLabel` in one step when I enlarge window in width. But the problem is appear when I try to reduce the window in width. In this case `componentResized()` calculate `width` step by step (and it's called multiple times), gradually decreases `width` by some amount of pixels till it reach real window size. It's behave in that way even thow I change window size in one step from maximum size to 800. Whole process is so slow, that it takes around a second to fit string to window size. So it looks bit like an animation.

The problem is very rare to me, bacause `width` in `componentResized()` method is calculeted step by step **only** when I assign `windowSize` variable.

When I give `windowSize` fixed size like for example 500 - `componentResized()` is called only onces - with correct `width` indicated real window size (!!) - and there's no its step by step decrease!

It's look like `width` variable which is assigned by `((JPanel) evt.getSource()).getWidth()` knows that `windowSize` is used to dynamically change size of `JLabel` component even before first call of `refresh()` method.

If anyone have an idea what is going on here - I will be very appreciate for help.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to adapt one of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3597550/230513) to better effect. As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3597688/230513), the ellipsis is supplied by the label's UI delegate via a call to [`SwingUtilities2.clipString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/swing/SwingUtilities2.java), which *appends* the `clipString`. Rather than re-invent the label UI, use [`TextLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998117/230513) to determine the required geometry, *prepend* the ellipsis, and handle the alignment in a table or list renderer, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15016292/230513).